Fix for sticky hover background in duplicates
Description
Problem
See bug report here: Duplicate modal - row hover state not cleared
The background is "sticky" added on hover then removed on a second hover.
Fix
This userstyle removes the sticky behaviour and only adds the style while hovering.

Installation
Prerequisites to install a userstyle
You need a userstyle manager like Stylus:

Stylus for Chrome - also works in Edge and Opera

Stylus for Firefox


Installing the userstyle
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
Code

/* ==UserStyle==
@name         Stack Exchange - fix annoying sticky duplicate window hover
@description  Fix for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400179/duplicate-modal-row-hover-state-not-cleared - hovering adds a sticky background remvoed on a second hover
@namespace    https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
@version      1
@author       VLAZ
@license      MIT
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("stackapps.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("stackexchange.com") {

/* remove the background-color alteration for the class */
.close-as-duplicate-pane .original-display .list-originals .list .item.hover {
    background-color: unset;
}

/* attach the background-color to the :hover pseudo-class and let the browser handle it */
.close-as-duplicate-pane .original-display .list-originals .list .item:hover,
.close-as-duplicate-pane .original-display .list-originals .list .item.hover:hover {
    background-color: var(--black-200);
}

}

